# How to using GetChanges() in DataTable

Tags: c#

I have been developing some application with DataGridView binded to DataTable. So, now I need to do 1 thing: user can edit some fields, and when he clicks by "Save" the application must change some fields programmatically. I'm trying to use this code, but it doesn't work:

```
private void toolStripMenuItemSaveChanges_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    try
    {
        dataGridViewPersons.BindingContext[table].EndCurrentEdit();
        //
        DataTable changes = table.GetChanges();
        if (changes != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("edited rows=" + table.GetChanges().Rows.Count);

            foreach (DataRow row in changes.Rows)
            {
                row[29] = getRightBody(row, 7, 18);
                row[30] = "-";
                row[31] = getRightBody(row, 23, 25);
                row[32] = getRightBody(row, 26, 28);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("edited rows=0");
        }

        adapter.Update(table);              
    }
    catch (Exception exeption)
    {
        this.Text = exeption.Message;
    }
}
```

If there is edited rows, this code won't change fields in the binded DataTable; I thought that GetChanges() return DataTable with relations to the original DataTable, but now I know it's false. Please, tell me the decision. Thank you in advance.

Comment: No, it returns a new DataTable. Do you have a primary key in your table?

Comment: Tim Schmelter - Yes I do. But how does it help me?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y06xa2h1(v=vs.80).aspx Sidenote: If you want to nofify someone on SO you need to join first- and lastname like `@TimSchmelter` and you must prepend an `@`-sign.